# How to run a script on login whilst being hidden

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, login, startup

I have an applescript (scpt) script that I would like to run on login of a user.
I would like the script not be visible in the dock, menu bar, etc. (This would probably mean running it in the background or something.)

What would be the best way to do this?

Preferably, I would like it that it would not be easily noticeable that the script is being auto-run. Also, a way to somewhat easily remove the script from login would be helpful.

[If needed, I'll attach a copy of the script.](http://textuploader.com/orta) It's supposed to be a prank using the say command, any tips for improving the script would be nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of launching **Terminal** You can make something like:

```
repeat
    delay (random number from 1 to 5) -- Change the delay in seconds
    do shell script "say Hello"
end repeat
```

You can save it as an app and then change its Info.plist file to hide it from Dock. Simply add this line inside `Hello.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

To launch it on login You can add this app to Login Items.